# Issue with going through a list in view of mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making an mvc application-c# that uses data from a database and I am having trouble looping through the list in the view that is part of my model.
This is my code in the view:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.communications)
{
<tr>

    int i = 0;

    <td>@Model.student.FirstName @Model.student.LastName</td>

    <td>@item.Notes</td>
    <td>@item.Date</td>
    <td>
        @Model.employeeName[i]
    </td>
</tr>
 }
```

Comment: Can you also please post how your Model Class looks like ?

Comment: What trouble you are having?

Comment: This is my model:public class StudentCommunications
    {
       public People student { get; set; }
       public List<string> employeeName { get; set; }
       public List <Communication> communications { get; set;     }

Comment: I am unable to loop through the list of employeenames in my view using int i=0

Comment: You have c# variable declaration in html code without @ symbol (int i = 0). Additionally, What is that int variable doing? You don't increment it in loop, so it always remains 0.

Comment: @(int i =0 ); gives me an error

Comment: i missed out the end part of i++ so i do increment

Comment: I think you're looking for `@{ int i = 0; }`. Curly braces instead of parentheses.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i increment my i in the view, @{i++} doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Its okay. Solved my own issue, the i++ had to be out of the foreach loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try to replace your code with this

use item variable instead of Model so you can access values

```js
 @foreach (var item in Model.communications)
{
<tr>

    int i = 0;

    <td>@item.student.FirstName @item.student.LastName</td>

    <td>@item.Notes</td>
    <td>@item.Date</td>
    <td>
        @item.employeeName[i]
    </td>
</tr>
 }
```